# Law of large numbers

Tags: r, normal-distribution

Could someone help me, please, thank you !
I can only do this, am I doing it wrong?

```
rm(list=ls())
a = runif(1000,0,1)
b = pnorm(a, mean = 60.5, sd = 0.1)
mean = rep(1,1000)
for(i in 1:1000){
  mean[i] = mean(rexp(b,2))
}
n = seq(1, 1000)
plot(mean ~ n)
```

1 000 numbers  ~ (, ) distribution
Then calculate mean from first, first two, first three..., thousand of these random numbers and means and absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake here was using the probability norm `pnorm` instead of the quantile norm `qnorm`. You also use `rexp` when you can be using the `mean` function to find the means of the values within your normal distribution `b`.

```r
rm(list=ls())
a=runif(1000,0,1)
b=qnorm(a,mean=60.5,sd = 0.1)
avg= rep(1,1000)
for(i in 1:1000){
  avg[i] = mean(b[1:i])
}
n=seq(1,1000)
plot(avg~n)
```

To create a chart of the absolute residual between the calculated average you can simply subtract `60.5` by `avg`, take its absolute value, and plot that.

```r
residual = abs(60.5 - avg)
plot(residual~n)
```

I'd also recommend using `avg` in place of `mean`, as mean is already the name of a function within R.

Comment: Upvote but please remove the semi-colons, R is not C.

Comment: @Luke Trenaman, thank you for the help, I'll apply it to my real data !